# LDAP authentication: not able to login through GUI but able to login from console

Tags: 12.04, lightdm, authentication, ldap, ltsp

I am building a LTSP environment with LDAP authentication. I have configured the LTSP,LDAP server and client perfectly. I checked with `getent passwd` command in LTSP/LDAP client. I can see my LDAP users details.

When I booted my LTSP thin client, I am able to login with LDAP user credentials in **Alt+Ctrl+F1** mode. But, Not able to login through GUI( lightdm ). See the logs which is from LTSP/LDAP Client.

/var/log/ldm.log:

```
Apr 15 18:15:53: [ldm] INFO: started on client with IP address: 192.168.12.34
Apr 15 18:15:53: [ldm] INFO: calling rc.d init scripts
Apr 15 18:15:55: [ldm] INFO: authenticating with backend: ssh
Apr 15 18:16:09: [ssh] INFO: calling rc.d pressh scripts
Apr 15 18:16:32: [ssh] CRITICAL: no response, restarting
Apr 15 18:16:34: [ldm] INFO: started on client with IP address: 192.168.12.34
Apr 15 18:16:34: [ldm] INFO: calling rc.d init scripts
Apr 15 18:16:35: [ldm] INFO: authenticating with backend: ssh
Apr 15 18:17:55: [ssh] INFO: calling rc.d pressh scripts
Apr 15 18:18:18: [ssh] CRITICAL: no response, restarting
```

/var/log/auth.log ( LDAP Server ):

```
Apr 16 18:41:54 dennis sshd[2727]: Connection closed by 192.168.12.34 [preauth]
Apr 16 18:41:54 dennis sshd[2729]: Connection closed by 192.168.12.34 [preauth]
Apr 16 18:42:09 dennis sshd[2731]: Invalid user myusername from 192.168.12.34
Apr 16 18:42:09 dennis sshd[2731]: input_userauth_request: invalid user myusername [preauth]
Apr 16 18:42:09 dennis sshd[2731]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Apr 16 18:42:09 dennis sshd[2731]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=192.168.12.34 
Apr 16 18:42:11 dennis sshd[2731]: Failed password for invalid user myusername from 192.168.12.34 port 38059 ssh2
Apr 16 18:42:11 dennis sshd[2731]: Connection closed by 192.168.12.34 [preauth]
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score -1):

At the client side run the following:

## #authconfig-gtk

Now, try setting the Authentication Configuration as LDAP Password(in the Identity and Authentication tab). It worked for me.

Comment: Are you sure this applies to Ubuntu? `authconfig-gtk` [is not provided by any package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=authconfig-gtk&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any). I believe this is for RedHat/CentOS based systems.